# jQuery Mobile: selecting by ID doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've a strange problem with **jQuery Mobile**... Below is the **HTML** code of my application:

```
<!-- == START MAIN PAGE == -->
<div id="mainPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#addContactPage" 
                data-transition="slidedown"
                data-rel="dialog"
                data-icon="plus"
                data-iconpos="notext">Add a contact</a>
        <h1>My repertory</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            Welcome to your repertory! 
        </p>
        <ul id="contacts_list"></ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Made with <em>jQuery Mobile</em></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- == END MAIN PAGE == -->

<!-- == START ADD CONTACT PAGE == -->
<div id="addContactPage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My repertory: add a contact</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="addContactForm" action="#mainPage">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">      
                <input type="submit" value="Valid" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the main page is shown, I want to set an item inside the *<ul>* list:

```
//When the main page is created.
$('#mainPage').live('pagecreate',function()
{
    //Just after the page is shown
    $(this).bind('pageshow',function()
    {
        alert('Event triggered!');
        $('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>');
    });
});
```

So, here is my problem: when I start the application, this code works and the item is set.

If I open the "add contact page" (please note it's a dialog box) and just close it, this code works well too and the expected result is done.

But if I open the "add contact page" and then submit its form, the list becomes empty!
The *alert()* is done, so the event is triggered... But the list is empty, like if the *html()* method is not called.
I've tried to alert the value of *$('#contacts_list').lenght*, and it's 1, so the **jQuery** object exists!

Please note that I've done nothing during the submission of the form: there is no listener on its *submit* event.

And if I replace the code by this one:

```
//When the main page is created.
$('#mainPage').live('pagecreate',function()
{
    //Just after the page is shown
    $(this).bind('pageshow',function()
    {
        alert('Event triggered!');
        $(this).find('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>');
    });
});
```

Then it works well!

I really don't understand...

Why the expected result is done with $(this).find('#contacts_list') and not with $('#contacts_list') ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just a thought, if the object exists maybe you need to refresh the page. Try something like this: $(this).find('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>').trigger('create'); or $(this).find('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>').page('refresh');

Comment: Thanks but it doesn' work: the first code changes nothing whereas the second one triggers an error: _cannot call methods on page prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'_. And I remind that `$(this).find('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>');` works well, it's this code that doesn't work: `$('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>');`. It's like if the two **jQuery** objects don't refer to the same DOM element!

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like your submission of the form causes a second event to be bound to the pageshow. What happens if you remove (or alter) the Action on the the form?  Also, try:

`$(this).unbind('pageshow').bind('pageshow',function()...`

EDIT

I think the outer function might well be redundant.  Why not simplify the whole lot to:

```
$('#mainPage').live('pageshow',function()
  {
    alert('Event triggered!');
    $(this).find('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>');
  }
);
```

Comment: The same problem occurs when I remove the Action from the form. But if I try to unbind _pageshow_ event before bind it, a strange behavior happens: the first time I submit the form the list is still empty, but the second time it works as expected... I don't understand why! Furthermore, it's like _pagecreate_ is trigerred every time the page is shown: I thought it was trigerred only after the creation of the page...! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: In that case, it sounds like the 'live' evnt is being duplicated. Try: `$('#mainPage').die('pagecreate').live('pagecreate',...`

Comment: The same problem as `$(this).unbind('pageshow').bind('pageshow',function()...` occurs. Is this behavior a bug from **jQuery Mobile** or something else?

Comment: Answer to your edit: the **jQuery Mobile** documentation recommends to use _pagecreate_ event. Theorically, this event is trigerred once, isn't it? Anyway, the code you propose has the same problem : `$(this).find('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>');` works well, but `$('#contacts_list').html('<li>Reset list!</li>');` results with an empty list. Maybe it's because I use Google Chrome on a desktop computer and not on a mobile device?